# How would I split a sentence into variables, then list it

Tags: python, list, split

I need to take a sentence or simply a set of words, split each word into an individual variable, then list them. This is what I have so far:

```
sentence = input('Please type a sentence:')
sentence.split(" ")

words = []
words.extend([sentence.split(" ")])
print(words)
```

I'm using the words `"one two three"` as an input to test the code. With this example sentence, the intended output is `[one, two, three]` then, I should be able to all on the separate variables later so: `words[2]`

The problem is that the list `"words"` is only receiving the split sentence as one variable single variable so the output becomes `[[one, two, three]]` and there's technically only one variable.

Also: I am an utter noob to programming in general, and this is my first post So, forgive me if I've missed something blatantly obvious,

Comment: Your two lines to initialize words are redudant.  Why not just `words = sentence.split(" ")`?

Comment: `words=sentence.split()` (no `" "` or any extra brackets).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sentence = input('Please type a sentence:')
templist = sentence.split(" ")

words = []
for x in templist:
    words.append(x)
print(words)
```

OR

Alternative:

```
sentence = input('Please type a sentence:')
words = sentence.split(" ")
print(words)
```

Explanation:

Get the sentence to `sentence` variable

```
sentence = input('Please type a sentence:')
```

Split the sentence using split function with space as delimiter and store in templist

```
templist = sentence.split(" ")
```

Iterate over the words in templist and append each word into `words` list

```
for x in templist:
words.append(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
words = sentence.split(" ")
```

should solve your problem. `split` by itself return a list.

Answer (score 0):

`split` it self returns a list and again you putting in another `[]` so it getting nested

```
words.extend(sentence.split(" "))
```

or you can directly assign the list above

```
words = sentence.split(' ')
print (words)

#out
[one, two, three]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a list to "words" (which already is a list). You can do either of these two things:

- Use : `words = sentence.split(" ")`
- If you want to add more entries later, and want to use the extend function, use :

  `words = []
   words.extend(sentence.split(" "))`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
words = []

def split(sentence):
    words = sentence.split(" ")
    return words


words = split("and the duck said: Woof")
print(words)
```

the code is pretty self explanatory but for the sake of completion:

1. i make a array called words
2. i make a function that will split a sentence for us
3. i call the function and put what is returns in words

and the output look something like this

> ['and', 'the', 'duck', 'said:', 'Woof']